# Complex Query in Cake Php

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, find

I have a question related with complex find conditions in cakephp.
I have a transaction table who has many transaction_item(is a table with structure product_id,date) and the products has many to many connection with the suppliers. So I use a map table for products and suppliers and in transaction_item table I use a foreign key for the transaction. My question how can I read the suppliers and their related products knowing the transaction id.

example.

Knowing transaction.id = 9;

I want the result

```
Supplier id:1
   Transaction Item 1
   Transaction Item 2
Supplier id:2
   Transaction Item 1
   Transaction Item 3
```

In SQL my query is

```
SELECT 
      `map_table`.`supplier_id`, 
      `transaction_item_table`.`id`
   FROM
      `transaction_item_table` 
         INNER JOIN `map_table` 
            ON `transaction_item_table`.`id` = `map_table`.`product_id`
   WHERE    
      `transaction_item_table`.`transaction_id` = 9 
   ORDER BY 
      `map_table`.`supplier_id`;
```

Comment: for future, when posting your questions, if you want formatting to look as typed without HTML, just highlight the area of content and click the open/close curly bracket button above the editing area to "format" instead of using direct HTML.

Answer (score 0):

In TransactionController in the function where you want to get that list:

```
$transactionId = 9; //For your example ;-)
$this->Transaction->Behavior->attach('Containable');
$result = $this->Transaction->find(
    'first',
    array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'Transaction.id' => $transactionId
        ),
        'contain' => array(
            'TransactionItem' => array(
                'Product' => array(
                    'Supplier'
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Above code should do the trick (if I understand your question correctly), assuming that you have:

- Transaction hasMany TransactionItem
- TransactionItem hasOne Product
- Product hasMany Supplier

If the Models have different names, you'll probably have to modify my example to reflect the appropriate Model names. If the relations are different, it might not work at all..

Also, have a look at [ContainableBehavior](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/1323/Containable)

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->TransactionItemTable->find('all', 
    array( 
        'fields' => array(
              'MapTable.supplier_id', 
              'TransactionItemTable.id'
    ),
    'joins' => array(
        array(
            'table' => 'map_table',
            'alias' => 'MapTable',
            'type' => 'INNER',
            'conditions' => array(
                'TransactionItemTable.id = MapTable.product_id'
            )
        ),

    ),
    'conditions' => array('TransactionItemTable.transaction_id' => 9),
    'order' => array('MapTable.supplier_id'=> 'ASC'),
    'recursive' => -1
  )
);
```